# IOS8 App Supports for IOS 7 and IOS 6?

Tags: iphone, ios7, ios6, ios8

I am going to develop an Iphone application in IOS8.But I have no idea whether it will work on IOS7 and IOS6.Can anyone clarify my doubts with clear explanation?

Thanks & Regards
Sam.P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would only support the older OSes if you didn't use any features exclusive to the newer OSes, and if you targeted the old OS when building the application. There is nothing stopping you from doing so, except that you will miss out on a lot of the new technologies (and adoption of recent iOS versions is very high traditionally among Apple's customers, so it isn't a huge issue generally to only support the latest version).

Answer (score 0):

You must make this decision before you publish your app, the earlier the better. You can support all OSes starting from 6 and only use APIs and features available in 6. Or use all the new features of the 8 and make the app incompatible with the earlier versions.

Each published app has a target OS version. If you specify 8 then users with earlier OSes simply won't see your app in the app store. However it's not sufficient to set your target to 6 to support earlier system. You must be careful in using the APIs: each has a documented version where it became available. And you must test, at least in simulators with different OS versions. iOS 6 simulator is still available as a separate download for Xcode 5. I'm not sure about Xcode 6.

iOS 7 adoption wasn't as overwhelming as with earlier updates because Apple made big changes in the UI. So the iOS 6 user base is still significant. I think it still makes sense to support iOS 6 for a new commercial application.

Comment: Just to add some stats, iOS 6 usage is around 11%. (source: http://cir.ca/news/apple-releases-ios-7)